# What makes BertGeneration and/or RobertaForCausalLM causal models? Where does the causal attention masking happen?

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, roberta-language-model

I am trying to use RobertaForCausalLM and/or BertGeneration for causal language modelling / next-word-prediction / left-to-right prediction. I can't seem to figure out where the causal masking is happening? I want to train teacher forcing with the ground-truth labels, but no information from future tokens to be included in the attention mechanism. For that I thought the model would need causal attention masking, but I don't see it being applied anywhere...

If anyone could point me to where this might be happening or why it is unnecessary, that would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have found it. It happens in `get_extended_attention_mask` in [modeling utils](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/modeling_utils.py#L742). Consider this question solved :slight_smile: